# How do I set a database column to the empty string in a Rails fixture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I have a varchar column in Postgres, defined as `t.string` in my Rails schema.rb

I want to set it a specific record written as a fixture in my specs, to the empty (zero length) string, rather than NULL.

Trying this:

```
fixture_1:
  my_column: <%= '' %>
```

does not work - it instead is saved as NULL.

How do I set it to the blank string instead?

Comment: does `my_column: ""` not work?

Comment: Doh. Yes, it did. Happy to accept that if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Try This

```
fixture_1:
 my_column: ""
```